# How to Build a List from Separate Lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I suspect this is a duplicate, but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

A routine problem I have is the following.

I have a set of data in three (or two, or more) lists:

```
l1={a1, a2, a3}
l2={b1, b2, b3, b4}
l3={{c1, c2, c3, c4}, {d1, d2, d3, d4}, {e1, e2, e3, e4}}
```

where `c1` is a result under condition `{a1, b1}`, `c2` is a result under condition `{a1, b2}`, etc.

I want to create the list:

```
{{a1, b1, c1}, {a1, b2, c2}, {a1, b3, c3},{a1, b4, c4}, {a2, b1, d1}, ...}
```

in preparation for creating a string to export to a text file.

My current solution:

```
Map[Transpose[{l2, #}] &, l3]
MapIndexed[Prepend[#1, l1[[#2[[1]]]]] &, %, {2}]
Flatten[%, 1]
```

This works, but the solution isn't intuitive to me, which makes me think there's a better way.

Is there a preferred approach for this task?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will generate a nested list, in accordance with `l3`:

```
MapThread[Append, {Outer[List, l1, l2], l3}, 2]
```

> {{{a1, b1, c1}, {a1, b2, c2}, {a1, b3, c3}, {a1, b4, c4}}, {{a2, b1, d1}, {a2, b2, d2}, {a2, b3, d3}, {a2, b4, d4}}, {{a3, b1, e1}, {a3, b2, e2}, {a3, b3, e3}, {a3, b4, e4}}}

`Flatten`ing once will give you what you want:

```
Flatten[MapThread[Append, {Outer[List, l1, l2], l3}, 2], 1]
```

> {{a1, b1, c1}, {a1, b2, c2}, {a1, b3, c3}, {a1, b4, c4}, {a2, b1, d1}, {a2, b2, d2}, {a2, b3, d3}, {a2, b4, d4}, {a3, b1, e1}, {a3, b2, e2}, {a3, b3, e3}, {a3, b4, e4}}

If you're not interested in the nested list above, then you can get straight to the result with

```
MapThread[Append, {Tuples[{l1, l2}], Flatten[l3]}]
```

> {{a1, b1, c1}, {a1, b2, c2}, {a1, b3, c3}, {a1, b4, c4}, {a2, b1, d1}, {a2, b2, d2}, {a2, b3, d3}, {a2, b4, d4}, {a3, b1, e1}, {a3, b2, e2}, {a3, b3, e3}, {a3, b4, e4}}

(in effect, `Flatten`ing before `MapThread`ing).

Comment: Hmmmm. Tuples and Outer were new to me. I see how they simplified things. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
Join[Tuples[{l1, l2}], ArrayReshape[l3, {Times @@ Dimensions[l3], 1}], 2]
```

> {{a1, b1, c1}, {a1, b2, c2}, {a1, b3, c3}, ...}

Though if the elements of `l3` are list of equal length, then `ArrayReshape`/`Dimension` won't work.
To avoid that problem you could write

```
ArrayReshape[Riffle[Tuples[{l1, l2}], #], {Length[#], 3}] &[Catenate[l3]]
```